# Withdraw tax of a product if its price is above 7?

Tags: magento-1.7, price, tax

I want to withdraw tax of a product if its price is above 7 . How can I do that? I tried price rules and tax rules. But unfortunately failed to figure it out. please share if you know.

Comment: You mean calculate tax only if product price above 7?

Comment: No only if below 7...

Answer (score 2):

Open products list and filter products with price above 7. And mark all found products. Select "Update attributes" action and change "Tax Class" to "None". By the way all products with price above 7 changed to as "Non taxable" goods. And you can set particular tax class to products with price below 7 and Magento will calculate tax for only products which is price below 7. And you can configure tax excluding/including and displaying options via admin->system->config->[sales]->[tax].